# Set the altitude/ height of a google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with markers and adding them like this:

```
markerLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(35.6412142,139.6988337);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: markerLatLang, map: map});
```

When I go in to street view all the markers are at ground level. Is there a way to position a marker at x meters above ground or at a set altitude?

[image: Example of marker on 5th floor of building]

Comment: there is no such option for google-maps/streetview

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as Dr.Molle said, this option doesn't exist in Google Maps API for now.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using a PNG image having bottom empty space how much you want. I also did not find a proper way to do that but this trick may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the y position/altitude of the marker by adjusting the anchor property of the icon object. The anchor is where the image is placed relative to the marker like translating in CSS.

```
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatLang,
    map: map
    icon: {
        ...
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 250)
    }
});
```