# google map streetview display marker in my POV or beside me

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

my custom marker is draggable and located in my current location.

However, I need to change my position first before I could see my custom marker so that I could drag it to wherever I want to put it.

Is there a way my custom marker pins in front of me or beside me as long as I see them immediately.

*added  working API key which is free for use on Stack overflow*

```js
var position = { lat: 42.3456778143501, lng: -71.09837363184101 }
var pano_heading = 68.85497936110396;
var pano_pitch = 14.77626025895016;

function initialize() {
    // Note: constructed panorama objects have visible: true
    // set by default.
    const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById("map"),
        {
            position: position,
            pov: {
                heading: pano_heading,
                pitch: pano_pitch
            },
            addressControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
            },
            linksControl: true,
            panControl: true,
            enableCloseButton: true,
        }
    );

    var marker_pano = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: panorama,
        position: position,
        title: 'test',
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });

    panorama.addListener("pano_changed", () => {
        //console.log('pano ID', panorama.getPano());
        const panoID = document.getElementById("pano-id");
        panoID.innerHTML = "pano ID = " + panorama.getPano();
    });

    panorama.addListener("position_changed", () => {
        const positionCell = document.getElementById("position");
        positionCell.innerHTML = "postion = " + panorama.getPosition() + "";
    });

    panorama.addListener("pov_changed", () => {
        const headingCell = document.getElementById("pano-heading");
        const pitchCell = document.getElementById("pano-pitch");
        headingCell.innerHTML = "pano heading = " + panorama.getPov().heading + "";
        pitchCell.innerHTML = "pano pitch = " + panorama.getPov().pitch + "";
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 80%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano">
  <div id="position"></div>
  <div id="pano-id"></div>
  <div id="position"></div>
  <div id="pano-heading"></div>
  <div id="pano-pitch"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that. Even offsetting the Marker Icon doesn't seem to work. You *could* use a transparent PNG image for the Marker with some blank space at the bottom but that's not going to place it at the exact position you want it to be. Related (old) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987175/set-the-altitude-height-of-a-google-maps-marker

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thank you for the enlightment, what I did i set `marker` into `draggable: true` then drag the marker to where you want to be and save the marker. My problem i need to get out first in my current position (where i stand) so I can see the marker I put before I can drag. Is there a way I could drop the marker one step away from my location?

Comment: Another related (closed) question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35305940/1238965 - I am afraid I didn't understand your last question.

Comment: I edited the code snippet for you. In this case, my custom marker is now draggable and located in my current location. However, I need to change my position first before I could see my custom marker so that I could drag it to wherever I want to put it. Is there a way my custom marker pins in front of me or beside me as long as I see them immediately.

Comment: I also edited the question now. Sorry I think it's you active enough to answer the question. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: You mean you want to change your POV so that the marker is in view / so that you are facing the marker?

Comment: Either way which is convenient. My POV will adjust so that I can immediately see my marker or my marker is the one adjusting. But I think changing my POV so that the marker is in view is more convenient

Comment: Probably you can use the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry) (you need to load the library with the script) and offset your position (`computeOffset`) or the marker position so that it shows in front of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to *offset* the marker by 10 meters distance from your current position and to change the POV heading so that it faces the Marker.

Sounds like a better solution than to offset your own position, as doing so might end up somewhere where there is no Street View imagery available...

Note that you must include the Geometry library when loading the API script:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry`

```js
function initialize() {

  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3456778143501, -71.09837363184101);
  var marker_position = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, 10, 0);
  var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(position, marker_position);

  // Note: constructed panorama objects have visible: true
  // set by default.
  const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      position: position,
      pov: {
        heading: heading,
        pitch: -15
      },
      addressControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      },
      linksControl: true,
      panControl: true,
      enableCloseButton: true,
    }
  );

  var marker_pano = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: panorama,
    position: marker_position,
    title: 'test',
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  });

  panorama.addListener("pano_changed", () => {
    //console.log('pano ID', panorama.getPano());
    const panoID = document.getElementById("pano-id");
    panoID.innerHTML = "pano ID = " + panorama.getPano();
  });

  panorama.addListener("position_changed", () => {
    const positionCell = document.getElementById("position");
    positionCell.innerHTML = "postion = " + panorama.getPosition() + "";
  });

  panorama.addListener("pov_changed", () => {
    const headingCell = document.getElementById("pano-heading");
    const pitchCell = document.getElementById("pano-pitch");
    headingCell.innerHTML = "pano heading = " + panorama.getPov().heading + "";
    pitchCell.innerHTML = "pano pitch = " + panorama.getPov().pitch + "";
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 180px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano">
  <div id="position"></div>
  <div id="pano-id"></div>
  <div id="position"></div>
  <div id="pano-heading"></div>
  <div id="pano-pitch"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=geometry&v=weekly" async></script>
```

Comment: great. Thanks for referencing me this geometry API.

Comment: `var marker_position = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, 10, panorama.getPov().heading);`

I changed the 3rd parameter to `panorama.getPov().heading` so that the marker drops to where he is facing. thanks for this great API